# How create columns with C# in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

İ want to make an application. I want the code to create as many columns into a table as the number of columns I type into a Textbox. My main purpose in the application is to write a title(like a table) and add as many subtitles (column) as I want to it. but I can only add columns by combining the system code. I can only add columns by making changes in the code below, but what I want is to create a textbox on the form and add as many columns as the number written there.

```
`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s1, s2;
            s1 = textBox2.Text;
            s2 = "char(20)"; 
            try
            {
                baglanti.Open();
                SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Create Table " + textBox1.Text + " ( " + s1 + " " + s2 + " ) ", baglanti);
                komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
                baglanti.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Succes");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
}`
```

Comment: So what is your question here? Though the *real* problem here is the massive security hole in your code. You are injecting unsanitised values into your RDBMS.

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, but are you sure you're not just looking for an Excel workbook instead, or maybe a NoSQL document store? RDBMS systems don't do well with arbitrary table structures and constructing dynamic SQL safely is a pain.

Comment: What do you think would happen if someone entered `t(i int); CREATE LOGIN NewSA WITH PASSWORD = 'a', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NewSA;--` for their table's "name"?

Comment: To pull this off you'll have to write your sqlstatement string inside of a for loop that iterates as many times as the number in the text box. That should be pretty straightforward so it's not clear where exactly you are stuck. I agree with others though that 1) This feels like a solution for a problem you shouldn't be having (there is rarely a good reason to dynamically monkey with database objects) 2) Even written well, this will likely open a sql injection attack hole.

Comment: here's a helpful article on the horrors of sql injection is https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You also need to have `using` blocks on your connection and command objects, do not cache them, dispose immediately

Comment: So, you're reinventing SSMS?

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way. Instead of adding columns and tables dynamically, where you have potentially *many* tables following this format:

**User-created Table 1**

| Title | SubTitle1 | SubTitle2 | ... | SubTitleN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data for first table ... |  |  |  |  |

**User-created Table 2**

| Title | SubTitle1 | SubTitle2 | ... | SubTitleX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data for second table ... |  |  |  |  |

You should use two tables total, where the schema pretty much *never changes*, like this:

**Single Base Table**

| ID | TableName | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... |

**SubTitles**

| ID | TableID | SubTitle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | ... |
| N | 1 | ... |
| N+1 | 2 | ... |
| N+2 | 2 | ... |
| N+X | 2 | ... |

In the `SubTitles` table, first `ID` field is to ensure uniqueness within the table and allow referencing a specific subtitle, and the second `TableID` field is to relate back to the correct record in the first table. Both are needed.

Comment: Thanks. 
I did as you said, but when adding subTitles in the second table, I cannot add more than one header to the same ID. I combined the ID and Table ID in the database in SQL. Error text= System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ProjeUnsurları'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProjeUnsurları'. The duplicate key value is (11).
The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: `I combined the ID and Table ID in the database in SQL.` That's exactly what you should **NOT** do. I used two separate fields in this answer for a reason. Each record in the `SubTitle` table needs it's own unique ID, and _also_ needs a reference to the parent TableID. I updated the answer to explain this.